# fread, fwrite for big size video file (about 180MB)

Tags: c, video, fwrite, fread

I want to read a video file and save as binary and write as a video file again.
I tested with 180MB video. I used fread function and It occur segmentation fault because array size is small for video.

those are my questions:

1. I use 160*1024 bytes char array. What is the maximum size of char array? How I can solve this problem?
2. this program need to work as:

   - read 128 bytes of video -> Encrypt -> write 128 byte
   - read next 128 bytes -> Encrypt -> write to the next.

I can't upload my code because of security rule of company. Any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first use `fseek()` with `SEEK_END`, then use `ftell()` to determine the file size, after that allocate the needed memory with `malloc()` and write the data to that memory.

If I understand you correctly you don't need to allocate so much memory, but only 128 Bytes.

```
char buf[128];
while(/* condition */)
{
  ret = fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, fp_in);
  encrypt(buf);
  ret = fwrite(buf, sizeof buf, 1, fp_out);
}
```